# Spring Security - Authentication not firing up

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot - Security project based on a example app, however the Rest Controller works fine, means,  I can access the rest resource but the security does not seem to fire up at all, so when I added a breakpoint as stated below it does not break there. Not sure why.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication() // breakpoint here
            .withUser("roy")
                .password("spring")
                .roles("ADMIN");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Here is the complete project hosted and editable with Codio: http://bit.ly/1uFI0t5

Comment: Try adding @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the framework which are the urls that it have to secure.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and().formLogin();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have this on the ResourceServerConfiguration in the OAuth2ServerConfiguration

Comment: BTW, the source I copied was from here https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

Comment: The problem with this code is that formLogin() cannot be resolved