# Secure REST with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I'm having some issue making this project https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth run. I cloned it and run `mvn spring-boot:run` and as soon as the Tomcat is launched on port 8080, I accessed it from the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting
```

But it says, `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContextunauthorized`

Comment: Have you looked into [this](http://thoughtfulsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/adding-security-to-spring-guides-rest-service/)?

Comment: A 403 response means your app is running and it is secure (I might have preferred a 401 for an unauthenticated request). So what's the problem?

Comment: @DaveSyer My bad, I did not go to the right process.. X_X anyway, I tried/ported this also with Spring Boot GAE *App engine and the security does not fire up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109189/spring-security-authentication-not-firing-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to access the resource:

```
curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=spring&username=roy&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"
```

Response will be like:

```
{"access_token":"ff16372e-38a7-4e29-88c2-1fb92897f558","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"read write"}
```

And put the token:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/greeting -H "Authorization: Bearer ff16372e-38a7-4e29-88c2-1fb92897f558"
```